# Swift Package Manager - Failed to parse the manifest

Tags: swift, manifest, swift-package-manager

I'm trying to migrate a CocoaPod to SPM.
It should be very simple, but for some reason I keep getting the error "Failed to parse manifest file".

The repo with the library an be found here: https://github.com/agcoesbenr/RBSManager/tree/swift-package-manager

```
// swift-tools-version:5.1
import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "RBSManager",
    platforms: [
        .iOS(.v10),
    ],
    products: [
        .library(
            name: "RBSManager",
            targets: ["RBSManager"])
    ],
    dependencies: [
        .package(url: "https://github.com/daltoniam/Starscream.git", from: "3.1.1"),
        .package(url: "https://github.com/tristanhimmelman/ObjectMapper.git", from: "4.2")
    ],
    targets: [
        .target(
            name: "RBSManager",
            dependencies: ["Starscream", "ObjectMapper"],
            path: "./RBSManager/Classes")
    ]
)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know from where you got only your error message, but it's incomplete. In Terminal.app, if you do `$> swift build`, you'll get this error:

```
$>swift build
/[...]/RBSManager-swift-package-manager: error: manifest parse error(s):
/[...]/RBSManager-swift-package-manager/Package.swift:21:39: error: expected ',' separator
            path: "RBSManager/Classes"
                                      ^
                                      ,
/Users/armel/Downloads/RBSManager-swift-package-manager/Package.swift:22:13: error: argument 'dependencies' must precede argument 'path'
            dependencies: []),
```

So a possible fix, would be:

```
targets: [
    .target(
        name: "RBSManager",
        dependencies: [],
        path: "RBSManager",
        sources: ["Classes"])
]
```

Then, you'll have another error:

```
error: manifest parse error(s):
Invalid semantic version string '4.2'
```

So `4.2.0` for `ObjectMapper` as it is in fact in [the repo](https://github.com/tristanhimmelman/ObjectMapper/releases).

I didn't fully check if the files where correctly added to the package, but it's more to explain how you could debug your issue and fix it. `sources`/`path` values I set might not be the correct one, I'll let you debug that part if needed.